# Can I change the opacity of everything OUTSIDE a DIV container?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking to highlight certain elements of my website by darkening everything OUTSIDE various DIV containers on my website. Is this possible? If so, what's the best way to do so?

Comment: You have two perfectly valid answers: 1 masks everything on click except the div you want highlighted, The other method (mine) masks everything and hightlight the divs. Want more options?

Answer (score 0):

This should put you in the right direction: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLBYXZ. You'll have new things to figure out, like getting everything back to normal.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .fade div{opacity: .4}
      .fade div.spotlight{opacity: 1}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>Hi</div>
    <div>Me</div>
    <div>Google</div>
    <div>Pizza</div>

    <script>
      var divs = $('div');
      var body = $('body');
      divs.on('click', function() {
        var self = $(this);
        body.addClass('fade');
        self.addClass('spotlight');
      });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

One possibility would be to have a (full-screen) element that covers/masks everything at a certain z-index with a certain opacity. Then make sure those elements that need to be highlighted have a larger z-index, so as to be not affected by the mask.